# PL/SQL procedure ERROR:(OBJECT IS INVALID)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, compiler-errors

when i tried to execute a procedure i got an error object is invalid & my code was about calculating interest
and MY COD WENT AS FOLLOWS

```
crete or replace procedure cal_intr
(P number,N number,R number)
is
si number(14,2);
ci number(16,2);
begin
si:=(P*N*R)/100;
ci:=power((1+R/100),N));
ci:=P*ci;
dbms_output.put_line('simple intrest is'||si);
dbms_output.put_line('coumpound interest is'||ci);
end cal_intr;
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

errors are 
SQL> exec cal_intr(1000,2,2)
BEGIN cal_intr(1000,2,2); END;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object HR.CAL_INTR is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: `crete or replace procedure cal_intr` I think you are confusing a Greek island with an Oracle directive? ;-p

Comment: no please 1ce again examine  the code is
create or replace procedure cal_intr
(P number,N number,R number)
is
si number(14,2);
ci number(16,2);
begin
si:=(P*N*R)/100;
ci:=power((1+R/100),N));
ci:=P*ci;
dbms_output.put_line('simple intrest is'||si);
 dbms_output.put_line('coumpound interest is'||ci);
end cal_intr;

Comment: When you get the message `Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.` you can use `show errors` (or `sho err` for short) to tell you what the compilation errors are.  You'll find it's much faster than using Stack Overflow users to eyeball your code.

Comment: yea yea got it.........

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo and won't be of help to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many closing brackets on this line

```
i:=power((1+R/100),N));
```

Try

```
i:=power((1+R/100),N);
```

And `crete` should be `create` obviously.

Comment: oooh i dint notice the brackets and i was strugling...:P thanks man anyways.... :)

Answer (score 0):

from:

```
crete or replace procedure
```

to:

```
create or replace procedure
```

?

Comment: sorry it was my typing mistake here but i typed as create itself in comand line and  i am able to execute a procedure with in and out parameters please help my friend